# Aligning divs that are not related

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gxbfu <-- Here is the bits of the site I'm trying to align.

What I'm trying to achieve, is Onyx Design to align with the right side of the navbar, or navbar to scale to the end of "Onyx Design".

The text is not related to the navbar, unless uncle is a term used for div relations.

jQuery/JS IS an option, as I will have that on the site when I get to making it functional.

Here's what I want to make it look like
http://puu.sh/5cq82.png

Divs that matter;

`.titling` contains the header, and has the `border-top` and `border-bottom`
`.bottomheader` contains `.navbar` (the white strip with icons on) and the heart button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used this piece of code:

```
h1
  max-width 300px
  width 300px
  text-align right
```

Might not be the best one, but suits your needs.

#### Fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/phAHc

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't realize this. Thank you kindly mi amigo.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know how long the navbar will be you can use some javascript (with jquery) to set the width:

```
$(function(){

   var h1 = $('.titling>h1');
   var navbar = $('.navbar');      
   h1.css({width: (navbar.width() + 'px'), 'text-align':'right'});  

});
```

Forked: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxrDF